# How to install an IPA with Windows now that iTunes no longer includes App Management

Tags: itunes

I made an app for someone to use but it's not meant to be on iTunes.  It's just a standalone privately used app.  They don't have an apple account (I do of course) and I have an IPA.

So I just wanted to give them an IPA and a way they can install this IPA on their iPad independently.

I was able to do it on my Mac using Apple Configurator 2 brilliantly but this is an OSX only app.

Another thought might be to install an older version of iTunes on a PC and do it this way, but I'm trying to imagine the modern way to achieve this with the changes in iTunes 12.x

Comment: [Apple.SE] may be a good site for this question, **as long as it satisfies their [guidelines](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Answer (score 7):

You can install IPA files by using iMobileDevice for Windows CLI tool. It is based on the Apple USB drivers so you need to install first iTunes for Windows.

1. iTunes for Windows: https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/ 
   *(When you open iTunes, you may receive a message that the application is not the latest. In this case, download it from the Microsoft Store.)*
2. Download and unzip one of the iMobileDevice for Windows distribution: http://docs.quamotion.mobi/en/latest/imobiledevice/download.html
3. After that, you have to pair your device with the PC. This can be done using iTunes or you can use this command also (it's in the MobileDevice.zip):

   `idevicepair pair`
4. Press 'Trust' on the device and use this command to install IPA files:

   `ideviceinstaller -i MyApp.ipa`
5. To remove the installed IPA, refer to the app ID:

   `ideviceinstaller -U com.your.appid.dev`

Comment: This saved my life, sometimes I was unable to install the Apple ATS Utility via iTunes and  only resetting the device made it work again. With ideviceinstaller it works without problems!

Answer (score 1):

I used iMazing. You can go to "Manage Apps" and then to "Device". Here you can drag and drop the ipa file (Ad-Hoc). If you connect your device the first time you have to enter your Apple account data.

This also works if you haven't installed the latest iTunes version (> 12.6) ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use cydia impact tool on Window to side load IPA without any apple certificate, except an apple Id. But it will expire after 7 days and you need use tool again.